# Why is there an EMF induced across a ring falling in a magnetic field in a manner such that the area vector is parallel to it?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, electromagnetic-induction

I had an exam today, wherein an object was falling via a magnetic field  such that the area vector was parallel to  the field (uniform), the question was is  an EMF induced, my answer was no,as the rate  of change of flux was zero. however,the   answer   key said EMF is  induced, why  is   it induced?

Comment: If a ring falling, such that there is definitely no changing magnetic flux across the surface as it falls, there will be no emf induced across the closed loop due to that uniform field

Comment: my classmate   said that was  so due  to  accleration due to gravity, but that's not true,right? Thanks for the replyy!

Comment: One  more thing, this is true for any closed shape, isn't it?

Comment: why  will it have an EMF across two  points>

Comment: oh,ok.Thank you!

Comment: why does this expansion take place? Does it have something to do with minimizing energy?

Comment: I think I have got the orientation wrong. I have no idea why they said an emf is induced. Sorry for the confusion, a current carrying loop in a magnetic field tends to expand because the force normally points perpendicular to the dl vector, if there was an emf induced if it fell with e.g rotation, the induced emf will cause it to expand. The only possible resultant geometry is therefore circle

Comment: ah,I  see, but  won't expansion by lorentz  force require currernt?

Comment: the conductor was an equilateral triangle.

Comment: sorry  for  the   typos,my  keyboard  iss't working   properly

Comment: my best guess is that switching to the accelerated frame changes some of the magnetic field lines to electric field lines.

Comment: oh,ok.Thanks  for  the help!

Comment: that is not correct @Habouz. The emf is measured with respect to the rest frame. in this frame, there is no emf.

Comment: the answer is that you misread the question, or the answer key is wrong.

Comment: @jensenpaull Yes thanks for correcting me.

Comment: @jensenpaull thankss!

Comment: @Habouz,thanks!